# ubuntu not able to recognise python command

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, python-2.7

I am using ubuntu 16.04 and installed new version of python 3.5. But I don't need it anymore so I deleted the executable file from `/usr/bin`. But now I don't know how to set python to the default version that it was already installed (python 2.7).

When I run the `python` command on terminal it generates the error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/python3.5: No such file or directory
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: python3 was already installed - you didn't need to install it, and you shouldn't have messed around with it :( Ubuntu needs python3! If you have changed symlinks to set the default version this *might* help [How to set Python back to the original version](//askubuntu.com/a/802144) but you need to reinstall python3 - see [I deleted package 'python3' on Ubuntu and I have lost dashboard, terminal and Unity. Help me to restore my data please](//askubuntu.com/a/810914) and I don't know how badly you already broke things so can't be sure this will fix it

Answer (score 0):

Use the update-alternatives program to update the default executable 'python', or any other default executable, to the one provided by 2.7